# DocuSign Connect API - check box behavior on DEMO site is not the same as PROD

Tags: docusignapi

Our system is using DocuSign Connect API to generate envelopes.  We can generate them on the DS Production site as well as on the DS demo site.  The same code base is used to generate envelopes on either site.  In both environments, our envelopes have exhibited the same (correct) behavior with respect to checkbox tabs for a long time.

Until recently, that is, when we noticed different behavior on the demo site.

The issue we now see on the demo system is that when an envelope contains multiple checkbox tabs, checking one of the checkboxes will automatically check all the others on the document (unchecking will then uncheck them all).

We have verified that these same envelopes when generated on the production site behave correctly (that is, the checkboxes are independent of each other when checked/unchecked).

I should also point out that our system has been in place for years, and we have confirmed that our code used to generate demo DocuSign documents is identical to the code used to generate production DocuSign documents.

But when I view the html generated by the DocuSign system for the signing experience, the 'input' element generated for the checkbox is different in the prod system vs the demo system.

My concern is that there has been a change made to the DocuSign demo system that will soon get pushed to the production site (which has been advertised for next week).

If so, I need to know what can be done (whether on my end or on the DocuSign side) to address this.

Answer (score 1):

If you see multiple checkboxes being checked/unchecked in unison as you described, that would imply that the checkboxes all have the same tab name/label. Please confirm that the checkbox tabs have unique names if you want them to be independent.

Comment: Luis, the names are unique for each of the 'CheckBox' tabs.  And as I mentioned, these envelopes when generated on the DocuSign production site behave correctly.

Comment: I'd recommend escalating this particular scenario to DocuSign support and have sample envelopeID's available so they can triage.